# Designing dimmer circuit for main

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, safety, isolation

I saw a dimmer on [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-light-dimmer-The-circuit/) and try to create circuit and pcb for it. However the it looks nice and probably will work but I'm not confident the reliability on long run.
So my question would be if this design violates some safety rules or not.
[image: PCB designer]
[image: PCB front]
[image: PCB back]
[image: Schema]

Yes I know the resistors don't have value yet but I still analyzing the datasheets of the optocouplers and the triac I have. (Probably will result more question(s))

Comment: Your mains traces look awful small..

Comment: I use one or maximum two 8W dimmable which result about 70mA current. I thought only the current is matter regarding the trace width. The voltage influence only the distance between traces.

Comment: OK as long as you can guarantee that ;D

Comment: YOu could ditch that bridge rectifier if you use an AC optocoupler... https://www.google.ca/search?q=ac+optocoupler+zero+cross&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ4JTEx8vYAhUH7YMKHQnJAz0Q_AUICigB&biw=1680&bih=972#imgrc=0EaSRv9dkS8tcM:&spf=1515524222151

Comment: Does your triac have low enough holding current to support 70 mA?

Comment: @Trevor On the bright side, in the event of a short those traces should act like a fuse :P

Comment: @winny I checked the datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/bt137-600e.pdf . It says the holdig current typical 2.5 mA and maximum 20mA. I hope it will work.

Comment: @Trevor_G I'll check the AC opto.

Comment: That's really low! Some new product made for modern LED fixtures perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is creepage protection for 2.5kV impulse from  IEC-664 cat II which requires an air slot gap in case of dust accumulation **shown by routed grey zones**.

The resistors must be rated for this as well and may need 4 parts for this.

Triacs use REFDES Q1 not D1 and trace width must support any surge current of expected loads.

It is bad practice to have Screen printing between high voltage exposed pads.

Comment: So every appliance in my household has to endure 2.5 kV surge? How to determine if a resistor is rated for that? I searched for 2.5kV rated resistors but one of them cost four times than the dimmable led bulb I try to drive and most of them are 150W beasts. -- REFDES -> understood -- You mean that the screen printing spoils the isolation provided by the trace distance?

Comment: Airgap: Where do You mean? On the LOAD and IN terminals it seems easy but between the triac legs I think there is no pcb manufacturer that can do it.

Comment: He never said that, he said your isolation barrier must withstand 2.5 kV peak. PCB cutout is free so if possible line up your optocouplers to make a well defined isolation barrier and make a wide and long cutout.

Comment: I thought that was what those grey rectangles were?

Comment: Good eye Trev. This view shows holes in grey with shadows

Comment: @Trevor_G Yes. It is the 3d view of the pcb of the kicad. Those grey "slots" are the cutouts. Any comment of the component placement or the routing? :)

Comment: @Péter it would be better to have the high voltage side and low voltage side divide on the same vertical line on the board.. and suitable silkscreen indication of which side is lethal. (Which is partly why I suggested ditching the bridge rectifier so you can do that) Having them staggered like that can confuse people about what is safe and what is not. Especially when they flip the board over.

Comment: @Trevor_G Unfortunatelly there is no collapsible markup and don’t want to flood the question with new designs. What woul be the ideal width for the cutout? How percentage of the pcb should remain to keep the two side together? I’ll search and place some warning signs, however I don’t want to mess around with board while attached to main :)

Comment: As I recall, it depends on the how dirty the intended environment it goes in,  ( e.g. high fan dust circulation/accumulation)  Often 2.5mm or 0.1" slot is used for low dust areas.